# Directly query databases with 1b rows of data using Tableau or PowerBI

Tags: sql, azure, bigdata, tableau-api

I occasionally see people or companies showcasing querying a db/cube/etc from Tableau or PowerBI with less than 5s of response, sometimes even less than 1s. How do they do this? Is the data optimized to the gills? Are they using a massive Db?

On a related question, I've been experimenting with analysing a much smaller dataset 100m rows with Tableau against SQL DW and it still takes nearly a minute to calculate. Should I try some other tech? Perhaps Analysis Services or a big data technology?

These are usually one-off data analysis assignments so I do not have to worry about data growth.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to answer this question objectively. We don't know anything about someone's database engine, resources behind the database (a service, a set of vm's), schema, queries, etc. We'd merely be guessing. And your related question: same thing. Dataset size (number of rows) doesn't say anything about your query, environment, etc.

Comment: Thanks David. Here's a more specific example if this helps. The 2b row nyc taxi data example.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1jnG1zIvTo

Other than using an S4, how would I get to this performance? The trips table still has to have 2b rows in it I presume, so it can't just be optimizing the data model.

Comment: Take a look at some of the following. http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/performance_tips.html

https://www.interworks.com/blog/bfair/2015/02/23/tableau-performance-checklist

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I definitely will try and optimize the data, but what's odd to me is that my single table has maybe 20 columns and no joins. Now I know I can go off and create half a dozen lookup tables from that and turn some 20 char strings into integers, but will it really make that much a difference vs 2b rows! I guess I'll need to do my homework and find out. I'm just making sure I'm not missing out on anything obvious like "Oh, they are running AS on top of Hadoop, that's why it's so fast!"

Comment: So I tried changing my 70m rows of data to all ints, created a star schema for 5 dimensions, and created a facts table that just contained dimension keys and measure values. Performance was generally decent, but not the massive uptick I was expecting. I'll have to do the same in both Tableau embedded and Tableau connected to SQL to compare but so far not that impressed. Still baffled on how 2b rows of anything queries quickly even if I shoved it all in cache in AS.

Answer (score 1):

Live connections in Tableau will only be as fast as the underlying data source.  If you look at your log (C:\Users\username\Documents\My Tableau Repository\Logs\log.txt), you will see the sql tableau issued to the database.  Run that query on the server itself...should take about the same amount of time.  Side note: Tableau has a new data engine coming with the next release.  It's called 'Hyper'.  This should allow you to create an extract from 2b rows with very good performance.  You can download the beta now...more info [here](https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2017/10/announcing-hyper-tableau-105-beta-77026)